# dockerfile composer install does not work

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I couldn't find a solution to this problem on the internet. I wrote a dockerfile file below.

```
FROM php:7.3.6-fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y sudo \
&& apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    sed \
    zlib1g-dev \
    git \
    zip \
    unzip \
    nano
RUN cd ~
RUN sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- -- 
install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN echo 'alias api="php api"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo 'cd /var/www/html/app' >> ~/.bashrc

WORKDIR /var/www/html/app

COPY composer.json composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.lock
RUN composer install

# Copy codebase
COPY . ./
```

running this code, installing dependencies with composer install doesn't seem to be a problem at all.

```
docker-compose up -d
```

and then

```
docker exec -it php /bin/bash
```

and then

```
cd app
```

vendor does not appear when I enter the directory with this command.I don't understand what the reason is. Can you help me how to solve the problem?

Comment: It looks like the last step `COPY . ./` copies over the composer install part

Comment: So how can I write?

Comment: Try not to copy composer.lock file

Comment: COPY composer.json composer.json
RUN composer install

# Copy codebase
COPY . ./

Comment: I've tried like this again did not happen.

Comment: The image fades all the time I tried every way.

Comment: I guarantee you that the container stood up by composer-install is not named "php".